# Firestore order by two fields

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In firestore I'm wondering if there is a way to have a hueristic1 and get all data between two hueristic1 values but order the results based on a hueristic2.

I ask because the data at bottom of both pages

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

there seems to be slightly contradictory documentation.

What I want to be able to do is

```
Ref.startAt(some h1 value).endAt(some second h1 value).orderBy(h2).
```

I know I'd probably have to index by h1 but even then I'm not sure if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update:

I didn't test this well enough to see that is doesn't produce the desired ordering.  The OP [asked the question again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47541360/4815718) and got an answer from a Firebase team member:

> Because Cloud Firestore doesn't support ordering by a different field
>   than the supplied inequality, you won't be able to sort by name
>   directly from the query. Instead you'd need to sort client-side once
>   you've fetched the data.

---

The API supports the capability you want, although I don't see an example in the documentation that  shows it.

The ordering of the query terms is important.  Suppose you have a collection of cities and the fields of interest are `population` (h1) and `name` (h2).  To get the cities with population in range 1000 to 2000, ordered by name, the query would be:

```
citiesRef.orderBy("population").orderBy("name").startAt(1000).endAt(2000)
```

This query requires a composite index, which you can create manually in the console.  Or as the documentation there indicates,  the system will help you:

> Instead of defining a composite index manually, run your query in your
>   app code to get a link for generating the required index.

Comment: "run your query in your app code to get a link for generating the required index."
what does this mean?
in my case the query is Cloud function how do i do it?

Comment: @RaghunandanGhagarvale: On the client side, running the query produces log messages that contain the link with instructions.  Check your cloud function execution log.  It may be the same there.

Comment: @Bob Snyder, I attempted the above implementation. However, I'm seeing empty results. **Query**: `.collection(ALL_COLLECTION).orderBy(TIMESTAMP)
.orderBy(QUALITY_SCORE).startAt(getTimeframe(WEEK))`. **Composite Index**: `timestamp DESC qualityScore DESC`. Perhaps I'm setting up my composite index improperly? I did not see an auto-generated link in Android Studio's Logcat.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing incorrectly. I wasn't seeing the auto-generated link in Android Studio before because I was looking under **Error** logs, not **Verbose**, etc.

Comment: It appears you are correct though, upon further review I cannot filter out based on my TIMESTAMP.