# Firestore order by two fields in one query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I asked a question a little over a week ago.
[Firestore order by two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381713/firestore-order-by-two-fields)

The response I got said that:

"The API supports the capability you want, although I don't see an example in the documentation that shows it.

The ordering of the query terms is important. Suppose you have a collection of cities and the fields of interest are population (h1) and name (h2). To get the cities with population in range 1000 to 2000, ordered by name, the query would be:

```
citiesRef.orderBy("population").orderBy("name").startAt(1000).endAt(2000)
```

This query requires a composite index, which you can create manually in the console. Or as the documentation there indicates, the system will help you:"

***But what this returns is not cities with population between 1000 and 2000 ordered by name but rather cities with population 1000 ordered by name followed by cities with population 1001 ordered by name followed by 1002 ordered by name and so on up to 2000.

I wondering if there is a way to get all cities between 1000 and 2000 in population ordered by name.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `where` clauses on `population`:

```
citiesRef
  .where("population", ">=", 1000)
  .where("population","<",2000)
```

Because Cloud Firestore [doesn't support ordering by a different field than the supplied inequality](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data), you won't be able to sort by name directly from the query. Instead you'd need to sort client-side once you've fetched the data.

Comment: would this qualify as invalid based on the example at the bottom of this page? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: When I try this on Android the result is: _Invalid query. You have an inequality where filter (whereLessThan(), whereGreaterThan(), etc.) on field 'population' and so you must also have 'population' as your first orderBy() field, but your first orderBy() is currently on field 'name' instead._

Comment: Oops, yep you're right. You'd likely need to query for cities by population, then sort client-side by name.

Comment: @Michael Bleigh - Unfortunately this is not a solution when using the FirestorePagingAdapter because the **FirestorePagingOptions.Builder** takes a **Query** as a param in the **setQuery()** method. In order to perform client-side sorting the data needs to be converted from a **DocumentSnapshot** into a list or array, and then sorted.

Any advice on turning a List or Array back into a Query format to pass into the **setQuery()** method?