# Is there way to use <= or >= function using in same query for let suppose for age and geo location

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

in this code getting error if someone can tell me details about it

> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(23009): Failed to handle method call
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(23009): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All where filters other than whereEqualTo() must be on the same field. But you have filters on 'age' and 'userGeoHash'

```
    enter code here
```

```
if (user.filtergender == 'Male' &&
         user.filtercounty.isNotEmpty &&
         user.filterCity.isEmpty &&
         user.filterReligion.isNotEmpty &&
         user.filterAncestry.isEmpty &&
         user.filterage0.isNotEmpty &&
         user.filterage1.isNotEmpty &&
         user.filterDistanz.isNotEmpty||
         user.filtergender == 'Female' &&
             user.filtercounty.isNotEmpty &&
             user.filterCity.isEmpty &&
             user.filterReligion.isNotEmpty &&
             user.filterAncestry.isEmpty &&
             user.filterage0.isNotEmpty &&
             user.filterage1.isNotEmpty &&
             user.filterDistanz.isNotEmpty) {
       print('Status Male/Female   w Religion   w Country ');
       key = usersRef
           .where('activeuser', isEqualTo: 1)
 
           .where('age', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: user.filterage0)
           .where('age', isLessThanOrEqualTo: user.filterage1)
           .where('userCounty', isEqualTo: user.filtercounty)
           .where('userReligion', isEqualTo: user.filterReligion)
           .orderBy('userGeoHash', descending: false)
           .where('userGeoHash', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: lower)
           .where('userGeoHash', isLessThanOrEqualTo: upper)
           .limit(userLimit)
           .getDocuments();
     }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore | Why do all where filters have to be on the same field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54969057/firestore-why-do-all-where-filters-have-to-be-on-the-same-field)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as a first step, why not do what the error message tells you to do, don't use multiple where calls, use a single where call:

```
.where('userGeoHash', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: lower, isLessThanOrEqualTo: upper)
```

and

```
.where('age', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: user.filterage0, isLessThanOrEqualTo: user.filterage1)
```

Comment: E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(23009): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(23009): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All where filters other than whereEqualTo() must be on the same field. But you have filters on 'age' and 'userGeoHash'still not working