# let the user to choose the type of sorting using firebase reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

i am creating a shopping list website and i want to make a dropdown menu from there the user can choose which type of ordering lists he wants( order by title asc, order by title desc) but in fire base you can only choose one type or ordering when fetching the data. for example :

```
 export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect(() => [
    {
      collection: 'lists',
      orderBy: ['title', 'asc'],
    },
  ])
)(Dashboard);
```

this is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import AllLists from '../lists/AllLists';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {compose} from 'redux';
import {firestoreConnect} from 'react-redux-firebase';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {db} from '../../config/firebaseConfig';
const Dashboard = ({lists, auth}) => {
  let test = db.collection('lists');
  console.log(db);
  if (auth.uid) {
    return (
      <div>
        <AllLists lists={lists} />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <Redirect to='/signin' />;
  }
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    lists: state.firestore.ordered.lists,
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
  };
};
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect(() => [
    {
      collection: 'lists',
      orderBy: ['title', 'asc'],
    },
  ])
)(Dashboard);
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as you mentioned and as clarified in this other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47541800/12767257), it's not possible to query it by neither more than one field or by a value choosen by a user. Since Firestore querying is very shallow, in regarding to available functions and choices on how to return data, this option is not included on its options.

The best option for you is to retrieve the data you want and then, once the user chooses the type of order that he wants - `asc` or `desc` as you mentioned - you will order it in the client side. This way, you can manage the format selected by the user and use it to order it with React.

Besides that, feel free to raise a Feature Request in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=0), so they can verify the possibility of implementing a different ordering in the feature.

Let me know if the information helped you!