# Firestore - Use a Where Clause and startAt with different fields

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm in a bit of a bind creating a query in Firestore's Android SDK. I want to limit documents to only those from the past week to reduce the number of docs, and also filter results using user-supplied text. I'd like to use a `whereGreaterThan` clause with the `created` field for the date, and `startAt` and `endAt` clauses for the filtering the `id` field.

However, there is a problem. The SDK requires that the first `orderBy` clause use the same field as the `whereGreaterThan` clause. On the other hand, the `startAt` and `endAt` also seem to be bound to the first orderBy clause.

```
Calendar oneWeekAgo= Calendar.getInstance();
oneWeekAgo.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
Query query = firestore.collection(BuildConfig.FULL_PATH)
.whereGreaterThan("created",oneWeekAgo.getTime())
.orderBy("created", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
.orderBy("id", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
.startAt(filter)
.endAt(filter + "z");
```

Is there a way to bind the .startAt and .endAt to the second orderBy? Or otherwise accomplish the goal of getting filtered docs from firestore created after a certain date?

If I delete the `whereGreaterThan` and first `orderBy` clauses, the query gets filtered results from all documents, not just those created in the past week.

Answer (score 1):

This a [limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations) of the API because Cloud Firestore doesn't support ordering by a different field than the supplied inequality. In this case you should order the data at client side, in this case your Android app. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47541800/12265927) too.