# How to retrieve posts of the last 24 hours and then sort them by clicks and then by timestamps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I run a query which retrieves only posts of the last 24 hours and sorts them by clicks and then by timestamps for those posts who have the same amount of clicks ?

Reference:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

This is what the docs explain is allowed (not the result I want):

```
getRef = global.db.collection("AllSubmissions")
               .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
               .where("timestamp", ">", date24)
               .orderBy('clicks', 'desc')
               .startAfter(theDoc)
               .limit(limit);
```

But this what I would like to have:

```
getRef = global.db.collection("AllSubmissions")
               .orderBy('clicks', 'desc')
               .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
               .where("timestamp", ">", date24)
               .startAfter(theDoc)
               .limit(limit);
```

For which I get the following error (as also explained in the docs):

Error:

> Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: timestamp and clicks

Is there another way to construct my query I missed or is this truly a Firestore limitation ?

P.S.: I do have indexes created for all compound queries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore order by two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381713/firestore-order-by-two-fields)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It doesn't but thank you for sharing (I already have queries with multiple "orderBy" that run fine, it's this one with a where() in that specific order that does not work)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It seems this can be achieved with MongoDB ? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/ Is there an easy way to export my firestore data to MongoDB or do I have to write custom code to restructure the data ? Or is there some way to achieve what I am looking to do with Firestore I am overlooking ?