# Multiple orderBy() not working in cloud firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Making a query on `firestore` which consists of multiple `orderBy()`.

```
val TAG = "TAG"
val firestore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val collectionReference = firestore.collection("/users")

collectionReference
    .orderBy("phone_number", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .orderBy("g")
    .startAt("abc")
    .endAt("abc")
    .whereArrayContains("common_query_str", "AbCd")
    .limit(5).get().addOnSuccessListener {
        it.documents.forEach {
            it1 ->
                Log.d(TAG, "data1: ${it1.data}")
        }
    }
```

**I've already built index** suggested automatically in the logcat. Removing the         `.orderBy("phone_number", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)` works but adding this to query **doesn't produce any error/log** in the logcat, doesn't fetch data from db either.

Here is the structure of DB:

[image: firestore database structure]

I've gone through this SO question [Firestore order by two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381713/firestore-order-by-two-fields)