# How Order data by two field in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How I can order data doc by two field, My app have a stream builder and I want order the data by the time that wrote and if the todo important so there is two field in docs one for time and there is boolen value
i want the data order by the time and if the data important that is mean the boolen true to be in the top of the list of stream and when i add data will show ender it. this the code I used for strem

```
final FirebaseFirestore firestore;
  DataBase({this.firestore});
  Stream streamTodos({String uid}) {
    try {
      return firestore
          .collection("homeNeeds")
          .doc(uid)
          .collection('homeNeeds')
          .orderBy('time', descending: true)
          .snapshots();

    
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
```

// i tried to put tow orderBy('time', descending: true).orderBy('pin', descending: true)
and it doesn't work the snap shot return empty

Answer (score 0):

it appears that is not as simple as saying you can or you can not, it depends on your specific case, but most likely you'll have to do it client-side.

[There is another question like this one here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381713/firestore-order-by-two-fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi_sort: ^3.0.0 in this case.

https://pub.dev/packages/multi_sort

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding Indexes in cloud firestore and that option allow you to use tow orderby in the same code